# Printing Crystal Report in loop

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

***My requirement is to generate/print mark-sheet of all student of a particular class at a single click, in crystal report.***

**WHEN I USED For loop** then it shows only the last record/page of the report.

AND My code is

private void btnGenerate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

```
        try
        {
            axCrystalActiveXReportViewer1.ReportSource = null;

            ReportDocument cryRpt = new ReportDocument();
            TableLogOnInfos crtableLogoninfos = new TableLogOnInfos();
            TableLogOnInfo crtableLogoninfo = new TableLogOnInfo();
            ConnectionInfo crConnectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo();
            Tables CrTables;


            crConnectionInfo.ServerName = Configuration.ServerName;
            crConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = Configuration.DataBaseName;
            crConnectionInfo.UserID = Configuration.Server_userName;
            crConnectionInfo.Password = Configuration.Server_password;



            CrTables = cryRpt.Database.Tables;
            foreach (CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table CrTable in CrTables)
            {
                crtableLogoninfo = CrTable.LogOnInfo;
                crtableLogoninfo.ConnectionInfo = crConnectionInfo;
                CrTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(crtableLogoninfo);
            }

           for(int i=0; i<=x; i++)
            {
                DataSet ds_ViewTermMarkSheet = new DataSet();
                Hashtable htViewTermMarkSheet = new Hashtable();

                htViewTermMarkSheet.Add("@Year", txtYear.Text);
                htViewTermMarkSheet.Add("@Faculty", cboFaculty.Text);
                htViewTermMarkSheet.Add("@Level", cboClass.Text);
                htViewTermMarkSheet.Add("@Section", cboSection.Text);
                htViewTermMarkSheet.Add("@term", cboTerm.Text);
                htViewTermMarkSheet.Add("@CRN",.ToString());

                DbOperations _dbAccess = new DbOperations();
                _dbAccess.selectStoredProcedure(ds_ViewTermMarkSheet, "spSelectExamView_Exam_TermWiseMarkSheet", htViewTermMarkSheet, "Marks");





            cryRpt.SetDataSource(ds_ViewTermMarkSheet.Tables["Marks"]);
           }



                axCrystalActiveXReportViewer1.Refresh();


            cryRpt.Close();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Mark Sheet generation was not successful.\r" + ex.Message, "Error!");
        }
    }
```

how can i append multiple marksheet at once and print them at once??

Answer (score 0):

You have to call :

```
cryRpt.SetDataSource(ds_ViewTermMarkSheet.Tables["Marks"]);
```

..from out side the for loop

In the for loop populate your datatable with all the information you needed. and then from out side the loop call the `SetDataSource() method.`

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Your code will loop and set the datasource multiple times , but will refresh the report just for the last one. You need to move the refresh indice the loop andalso print the report there:

```
        cryRpt.SetDataSource(ds_ViewTermMarkSheet.Tables["Marks"]);
        axCrystalActiveXReportViewer1.Refresh();
        // print the rpeort
       }
```

The right way to handle this is to create a report, which shows information about all the students. You can group by student ID or name and set a new page after the group. Then print this report ( just 1 time).